# In Chrono Trigger, I'm stuck in the future ruins with the seed

Tags: chrono-trigger

I got to the ruins in the future and I'm completely stuck. I'm using RetroArch's Snes9x Next core on my Android, so I'm unsure if this is a very specific emulation issue or I forgot something.

So, in Arris Dome, I know there's a rat you chase and it gives you the password or something. I've chased it maybe 9 times now and it just disappears once I reach it. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have the seed, but Doan doesn't do anything about it when I talk to him. He just tells me to come back alive like he did before. I leave and try to get out via Lab 32 but trying to go to the right just brings those Proto 2 enemies, and I've tried this three times to no avail.

What in the world do I do now? Googling for 20 minutes with my brother found nothing of use.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about Android, but in the SNES/DS versions, you have to press the action/talk button when you get close enough to the rat to catch it. Once you do that, it'll give you the password to move through the next room.